# Gstreamer error could not set property "caps" in element "udpsrc0" to "application/x-rtp ..."

Tags: windows, windows-7, gstreamer

Very very strange problem. A working pipe in my Linux boxes (fedora/ubuntu/bsd) does not work in Windows Xp/Vista (using Gstreamer for Windows).

- I have this following pipeline in Windows Vista also tested in Windows XP both same error throwing: how can i fix it? Is this a bug of gstreamer? The same parsing works in Linux terminal

  example:
  C:\gst-launch -v udpsrc port=1111 caps = "ap
  plication/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(stri
  ng)SPEEX, encoding-params=(string)1, frame-size=(string)480, payload=(int)96, ssr
  c=(uint)928237273, clock-base=(uint)2792682998, seqnum-base=(uint)62730" ! ...depay ! dec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink

  0:00:00.334065000   692   0088D708 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.tab.c:50
  8:gst_parse_element_set: could not set property "caps" in element "udpsrc0" to "
  application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(st
  ring)SPEEX, encoding-params=(string)1, frame-size=(string)480, payload=(int)96, s
  src=(uint)928237273, clock-base=(uint)2792682998, seqnum-base=(uint)62730"
  WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "caps" in element "udpsrc0"
  to "application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name
  =(string)SPEEX, encoding-params=(string)1, frame-size=(string)480, payload=(int)9
  6, ssrc=(uint)928237273, clock-base=(uint)2792682998, seqnum-base=(uint)62730"

Note: is this a unknown bug for some how? Please see no answer, what can it be?

http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/f/354/t/59113.aspx

http://www.mentby.com/steven-431/gstreamer-on-gumstix.html

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-udpsrc-in-gst-rtsp-server-td3327366.html

Comment: have you tried changing the caps params to determine which one is causing the fault?

Comment: Yes, same for always tried also such as \" or \\" or ' or \( , all causing same issue.

Comment: @SpliFF: see my following answer for this issue. Would be great if you can make it work. I just made it not to represent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing this portion `", ssr c=(uint)928237273, clock-base=(uint)2792682998, seqnum-base=(uint)62730"` the error does not appear. But it does not work at all when its removed (it just stop showing the error).

I would say windows Gstreamer is Buggy, it should simply allow the Linux standards, the same way it works with Linux, but not with Windows.